# Keep getting sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

Following [this Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/views/) I keep getting following error:

```
File "db.py", line 29, in init_db_command
init_db()
```

```
File "db.py", line 25, in init_db
db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))
```

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "author_id": syntax error

schema.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_tb;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

CREATE TABLE user_tb (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE post (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    author id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY author_id REFERENCES user_tb id
);
```

db.py:

```
import sqlite3
import click
from flask import current_app, g

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

`__init__.py:`

```
import os
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World!'

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from . import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)

    return app
```

I changed `user_tb` table from `user` to `user_tb` with no change. I changed foreign key name with no change. I used parentheses around `author_id` and `user_tb` id. It only changed from:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "author_id": syntax error

to:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near (: syntax error

Originally the error was:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near TIMESTAMP: syntax error

That was fixed by changing `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: (1) It seems that you sometimes use spaces in the SQL where underscores or dots should be. (2) After `FOREIGN KEY` one or more column names **in parentheses** are expected. See https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to Michael Butscher's comment. It looks like my author_id integer did not have an underscore while the foreign key author_id did. Also, when referencing the id of user_tb, only the id was supposed to be in parentheses. Here is the updated code block for the post table with the changes in asterisks:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
**author_id** INTEGER NOT NULL,
created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
body TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES **user_tb (id)**);
```